# Lucene any letter regex

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I have a problem with finding equivalent for `\p{L}` (any letter any lang) in lucene 5.5.0.

Does anyone know equivalent?

Comment: did you try this `\pL`

Comment: @vinod, yep I try in lucene 5.5.0. It doesn't work. It matches like 'pL'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene regular expression syntax does not have such a built in class.  The syntax available is documented by the [RegExp class](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html).

There may be other ways to support your end goals here (ie. with the right analysis).  If you would be inclined to post a question with more detail on what those goals actually are, perhaps this will turn out to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?